# Why counting the number of 1 digits that appear in all integers in 0-9, 0-99, 0-999, 0-9999 follow an arithemtic-geometric sequence?

Tags: arithmetic, arithmetic-functions

I noticed that

- 0-9 = has only 1 '1'
- 0-99 = has 20 '1's [1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91]
- 0-999 = 300
- 0-9999 = 4000

It follows the formula of

- n = number of digits in the sequence
- Formula : n*(10**(n-1))

I don't see why.

I hope the question is well formatted

Comment: It isn't an arithmetic sequence (neither as a function of $n$ nor as a function of $10^n-1$).

Comment: Might be easier to count the strings that do NOT have a 1.

Comment: @Randall notice that the OP counted 20, not 19 for the examples in the range 0-99.  That is to say, $11$ counted twice since it had two 1's in it, not just once.  Yours is a good observation if we were counting each number only once but it is unhelpful here.

Comment: This kind of sequence is called an *arithmetico–geometric* sequence.

Comment: @JMoravitz Your comment also answers the question why, in larger ranges, the number of 1 digits exceeds the number of numbers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the purpose of this question, let's consider that a number between $0$ and $999...9$ = $10^n-1$ ($n$ digits $9$) is always written with $n$ digits, by adding leading zeros when necessary.

Then all numbers from $0$ to $10^n-1$ included are the combinations of digits from $0$ to $9$ in $n$ places. The $1$ on digit $k$ is present on $10^{n-1}$ numbers, exactly on one-tenth of all numbers. As there are $n$ digits, there are $n 10^{n-1}$ digits $1$ in total.

Another way of saying it: with the leading zeros, there is a same quantity of each digit. As there are $10^n$ numbers of $n$ digits each, this makes a total of $n 10^n$ digits, where one tenth of that, i.e. $n 10^{n-1}$, are $1$.

Comment: I understand! n slots * 1/10 of 1's per slot * 10^(n-1) numbers!! Great answer thanks.